# System.TypeLoadException: Method 'Create' in type 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.MySQLSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitorFactory'

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to add a new user to the database with the following code:

```
public async void SeedUsers(){
    int count=0;
    if(count>0){
        return;
    }
    else{
        string email="jujusafadinha@outlook.com.br";
        _context.Add(new User{LoginEmail=email});  
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();  
    }
}
```

But it keeps giving me the following error:

> System.TypeLoadException: Method 'Create' in type 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.MySQLSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitorFactory' from >assembly 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=8.0.22.0, Culture=neutral, >PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' does not have an implementation.
> at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions.MySQLServiceCollectionExtensions.AddEntityFrameworkMySQL(IServ>iceCollection services)
> at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.MySQLOptionsExtension.ApplyServices(IServiceColle>ction services)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.ApplyServices(IDbContextOptions >options, ServiceCollection services)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.<c__DisplayClass4_0.g__BuildServiceProvider|3()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__2(Int64 k)
> at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.GetOrAdd(IDbContextOptions options, >Boolean providerRequired)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.EntryWithoutDetectChanges[TEntity](TEntity entity)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState[TEntity](TEntity entity, EntityState >entityState)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Add[TEntity](TEntity entity)
> at contatinApi.Data.SeedData.SeedUsers() in D:\dev\contatinapi\Data\SeedData.cs:line 24
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.b__139_1(Object state)
> at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.<>c.<.cctor>b__6_0(QueueUserWorkItemCallback quwi)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunForThreadPoolUnsafe[TState](ExecutionContext >executionContext, Action`1 callback, TState& state)
> at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.Execute()
> at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
> at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

The User class:

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id{get;set;}
        public string LoginEmail{get;set;}
        public string UserName{get;set;}
        public DateTime CreatedAt{get;set;}
        public List<Contact> Contacts {get;set;}
        public List<ContactList> ContactLists{get;set;}
    }
```

Both the EF Core and MySQL packages are updated. Also, i tried using stored procedures and it gave the same results.

The content of Ex was:

> The value of Ex was {System.TypeLoadException: Method 'Create' in type 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.MySQLSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitorFactory' from assembly 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=8.0.22.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' does not have an implementation.
> at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions.MySQLServiceCollectionExtensions.AddEntityFrameworkMySQL(IServiceCollection services)
> at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.MySQLOptionsExtension.ApplyServices(IServiceCollection services)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.ApplyServices(IDbContextOptions options, ServiceCollection services)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.g__BuildServiceProvider|3()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__2(Int64 k)
> at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.GetOrAdd(IDbContextOptions options, Boolean providerRequired)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.IDbContextDependencies.get_StateManager()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.EntryWithoutDetectChanges(TEntity entity) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
> at contatinApi.Data.SeedData.SeedUsers() in D:\dev\ContatinApi\Data\SeedData.cs:line 40}

Comment: hi, I am having this exact issue, did you ever resolve it?

Answer (score 25):

If you're using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0 downgrade it to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.10 MySQL EF 8.0.22 is currently not compatiable with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0

I have a working Code until I upgraded to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0 then I got same error, Downgraded and it worked!

Hoping to post a Bug report on MySQL Bug Forum

Comment: The [Pomelo](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/5.0.0-alpha.2) provider for MySQL has prerelease support for EF Core 5.0 if you'd like to try that.

Comment: @MarkG I'm using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 5.0.0-alpha.2 build. The same problem is still there.

Comment: Make sure you're using `UseMySql()` instead of `UseMySQL()` if you still have a reference to `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore` in your project file.

Answer (score 3):

I have resolved this issue following this:-

1. upgrade Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore to version 5.0.1
2. upgrade Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql to version 5.0.0-alpha.2
3. add the code blocks into ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs file

   var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("userDB");
   services.AddDbContext(options =>
   options.UseMySql(connectionString,new MySqlServerVersion(new
   Version(10, 1, 40)), mySqlOptions => mySqlOptions
   .CharSetBehavior(CharSetBehavior.NeverAppend)));

To get mysql server version run the query to any of mysql server editor like MySql Workbench or HeidiSQL

```
SELECT VERSION()
```

Answer (score 2):

While following an EF Core tutorial for MySql using Migrations and getting the error "Method 'Create' does not have an implementation" and lots of Googling, I Downgraded my csproj file from net5.0 to netcoreapp3.1:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
```

And included the following Nuget packages using terminal **dotnet** commands inside the project directory:

```
dotnet add package Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql --version 5.0.0-alpha.2
...

dotnet list package                    
    Project 'XYZ' has the following package references
       [netcoreapp3.1]: 
       Top-level Package                           Requested       Resolved     
       > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore             5.0.1           5.0.1        
       > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design      5.0.1           5.0.1        
       > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools       5.0.1           5.0.1        
       > Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql          5.0.0-alpha.2   5.0.0-alpha.2
```

As example, one of the model files is Student.cs:

```
namespace EFCoreTutorial.Model
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I created the db context file SchoolContext.cs with my personal connection string as:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure;

namespace EFCoreTutorial.Data
{
  public class SchoolContext : DbContext
  {
    public DbSet<Model.Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Model.Course> Courses { get; set; }
        
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
      string connectionString = "server=localhost;port=3306;database=SchoolDB;user=root;password=******";
      optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString, new MySqlServerVersion(new System.Version(8, 0, 22)), mySqlOptions => mySqlOptions.CharSetBehavior(CharSetBehavior.NeverAppend));
    }
  }
}
```

then you can create the database and the empty tables defined in the Model with

```
dotnet ef migrations add CreateSchoolDB <- just a label 
dotnet ef migrations list   <- to verify it is pending
dotnet ef database update   <- the database will be created/updated
dotnet ef migrations list   <- to verify
```

finally verify in mysql:

```
mysql> show databases;
mysql> use SchoolDB;
mysql> show tables;
```

Succes! The Database and tables were completely created from the models and DB Context definition.

Answer (score 1):

Install the following nuget package for MySql driver from [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/5.0.1)

Other Nuget packages will be:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.10" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.10" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.10">
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.22" />
<PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="5.0.1" />
```

Run the following command to get the version of your MySql

```
SELECT VERSION()
```

In Startup.cs add the following namespaces:

```
using System;
using IdentityWithEFPlayground.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql;
```

In ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs add the following code:

```
        var serverVersion = new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 26)); // Get the value from SELECT VERSION()
        string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<AppDBContext>(c => c.UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion));
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDBContext>();
```

In ther Terminal run the following command to update/create the database via EF Migrations:

```
dotnet ef migrations add IdentityUser
dotnet ef database update
```

You will see the ASP.NET Identity tables in your database:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me:
If you are connecting with the `MySql database` then use dependency `MySql.EntityFrameworkCore` instead of `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This was the best answer!!!!! Worked like a charm. All the other answers were such a hack. This is all that had to be done. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  _context.Users.Add(new User{LoginEmail=email, CreatedAt=DateTime.Now });  
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();  

or better 
try
{
var newUser= new User{LoginEmail=email, CreatedAt=DateTime.Now };
  _context.Users.Add(newUser);  
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();  
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
var errorMessage = ex.Message;
        
}
in this case you can get a new key if you need;
```

UPDATE:

```
instead of    _context.Users.Add(newUser);  

Try:

_context.Entry(newUser).State = EntityState.Added;
```

But why your ID of your User class doesn't have attribute [Key] and CreateDate doesn't have attribut   [Column(TypeName = "datetime")] ?. What kind of validations do you have? Can you post some of _context that is relevant to User?

Comment: The Id field(key) is set to auto increment directly into the database and there's no required fields in the user class.

Comment: What about     public DateTime CreatedAt{get;set;} . Can it be null? it should be public DateTime? CreatedAt{get;set;} or you have to assign date

Comment: It's also added directly into the database. I added them into de object and still got an error.

Comment: What do you mean by "It's also added directly into the database. "  and did you change _context.Add(newUser) to  _context.Users.Add(newUser)?

Comment: I changed to _context.Users.Add and still got the error. In the database, the field createdAt has the default value of Now().

Comment: This default values are very tricky. In order to trigger default value you have to post null value. DateTime by default has a very strange date so you have to change your class property to DateTime? or assign the real value before adding.

Comment: I tried using DateTime.Now on the object and still got the same error. Could it be the navigation properties(Contacts and ContactLists)?

Comment: I don't think so. I've used Add()  for thousand times and it always worked. Did you try to get users? Maybe it's problem with _context?

Comment: I updated code. Pls run it in debuger and check  var ex

Comment: Updated the question, ex value was exactly the same error.

Comment: Still same error. Could it be the MySQL package not being compatible with the current version of EF Core?

Comment: I am sorry but I  can't help you. I've never worked with MySql and will never recomend this DB to anybody. I prefer the professional applications not open source. EF core were created by Microsoft and for MS SQL mostly.

Comment: I noticed that your User class doesn't have any attributes? Can you post your DB context  USER part ?