# ASP.NET cannot connect to remote MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET project, I am trying to connect to remote database with `DbContext` and dependency injection. Problem is that I am getting error that server was not found.

This is my dependency code:

```
services.AddDbContext<GuestRecContext>(options =>options.UseSqlServer("Server=remotemysql.com;Database=XTkzdttrBY;Password=XXX;User Id=XXX"));
```

Note: All credentials are correct, I can connect to this database on phpmyadmin

Comment: So you are trying to use MySql or Sql Server? Because this _options.UseSqlServer_ seems not quite right for MySql

Comment: I need to connect to mysql database

Comment: Then you should use _options.UseMySql_

Comment: Method 'Create' in type 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.MySQLSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitorFactory' from assembly 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=8.0.22.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' does not have an implementation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64614651/system-typeloadexception-method-create-in-type-mysql-data-entityframeworkcor?msclkid=5defdd67a87911ec81fe1f98757a427e